# Setting relative paths for KMZs in Arc2Earth dialog?

Tags: kml, kmz, file-path, arc2earth

Using Arc2Earth, I'm converting a large vector dataset to a KML with regions.

The resulting kmz works great on my computer but the files paths are all actual paths and not relative, so they don't work on other computers or the server.

I would really prefer not to edit all of the resulting KML files, so I'm hoping somebody could help me figure out how to set a relative paths in the Arc2Earth dialogue box.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Arc2Earth so this is speculation. In ArcMap under File | Map Document Properties, you can check "Store relative pathnames to data sources". Does Arc2Earth process from an mxd? If so perhaps that could help.